# After clicking Export to Excel. in Excel Duration time is not Displaying correct

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, javascript-objects, kendo-asp.net-mvc

here i am trying to get correct Duration Time but i am not able to add Punch in and punch out time in Duration Column.

[image: In this Image i want to show correct duration time but i am not getting duration time correct]

i tried but i am not getting correct result as per my requirement help me.  when Excel file will download it should display correct duration time.

```
     @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
  .Name("TimeTrackingLogsGrid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Hidden(true).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;" });
      columns.Bound(c => c.IsDeleted).Hidden(true);
      columns.Bound(c => c.ApprovalRequired).Visible((bool)ViewBag.IsAdmin).ClientTemplate("# if (ApprovalRequired == true && Approved == false && '" + (ViewBag.IsAdmin).ToString() + "'=== 'True') {# Yes: <a data-ajax='true' data-ajax-complete='refreshGrid' data-ajax-method='POST' href='/Punch/Approve/#:Id#' class='grid-link' >Approve</a>#} else{# No #}#");
      columns.Bound(c => c.EmployeeName).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true).Search(true));
      columns.Bound(c => c.Month).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true));
      columns.Bound(c => c.PunchDate)
          .ClientFooterTemplate("#= getFormattdDate(data.PunchDate.min) # - #= getFormattdDate(data.PunchDate.max) # ")
          .ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("#:convetUtcDateToLocalDateByInput(value)#")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "utc-date", utc_date_value = "#:PunchDate#" });
      columns.Bound(c => c.PunchInPic).Hidden(true).Visible((bool)ViewBag.IsAdmin).ClientTemplate("<img class='punchPic' width='100' src='data: image / png; base64,#:PunchInPic#'/>").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;" });
      columns.Bound(c => c.PunchIn).Groupable(false).Filterable(false).ClientTemplate("#:PunchIn.Hours#:#:PunchIn.Minutes#").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "utc-time", utc_time_value = "#:PunchIn.Hours#:#:PunchIn.Minutes#" });
      columns.Bound(c => c.PunchOutPic).Hidden(true).Visible((bool)ViewBag.IsAdmin).ClientTemplate("<img class='punchPic' width='100' src='data: image / png; base64,#:PunchOutPic#'/>").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;" });
      columns.Bound(c => c.PunchOut).Groupable(false).Filterable(false).ClientTemplate("#:PunchOut == null ? 0 :PunchOut.Hours #:#: PunchOut == null ? 0 : PunchOut.Minutes  #").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "utc-time", utc_time_value = "#: PunchOut == null ? 0 : PunchOut.Hours#:#:PunchOut == null ? 0 : PunchOut.Minutes #" });
      columns.Bound(c => c.Duration).Groupable(false).Filterable(false)
          .ClientFooterTemplate("#= SecondsToTime(data.DurationInSeconds.sum) # ")
          .ClientTemplate("#:formatDuration(Duration.Hours,Duration.Minutes) #").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "" });
      columns.Bound(c => c.Comments).Visible((bool)ViewBag.IsAdmin).Filterable(false).Groupable(false).ClientTemplate("# if (ApprovalRequired == true && Approved == false && '" + (ViewBag.IsAdmin).ToString() + "' !== 'True') {# Please get this time log approved #} else{#<span class='comments' (#:Comments# == null ? '' : title='<ul>  #:Comments# </ul>')> view <span>#}#");
      columns.Command(command =>
      {
          //    command.Edit().Text(" ");
          command.Destroy().Text(" ");
      }).Width(50);
  })
  .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "" })
  //.Scrollable()
  .Groupable()
  .Sortable()
  .Filterable()
  .Navigatable()
  .ColumnMenu()
  .ToolBar(toolbar =>
  {
      //toolbar.Create();
      //toolbar.Save();
      //toolbar.Pdf();
      toolbar.Excel();
      toolbar.Custom().Text("Clear Filter").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "clearGridFilter" });
  })

  .Excel(exl => exl.AllPages(true).Filterable(true).FileName("Timesheet.xlsx")
      .ProxyURL(Url.Action("ExportSave", "Punch")))
  .Pdf(pdf => pdf
      .AllPages()
      .Title("Time Tracker Report")
      .Subject("Daily Activity")
      .AvoidLinks()
      .PaperSize("A4")
      .Scale(0.8)
      .Margin("2cm", "1cm", "1cm", "1cm")
      .Landscape()
      .RepeatHeaders()
      .TemplateId("page-template")
      .FileName("OfficeGx Result")
      .ProxyURL(Url.Action("ExportSave", "Punch"))
  )
  .Events(events => events.DataBound("convertUtcToLocal").PdfExport("onPunchReportPdfExport").ExcelExport("onPunchReportExcelExport"))
  //.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
  .Pageable(pageable => pageable
      .Refresh(true)
      .PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 20, 50, 100, 500 })
      .ButtonCount(5))
  .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
  .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
      .Ajax()
      .Filter(f =>
      {
          f.Add(field => field.IsDeleted).IsEqualTo(false);
          //f.Add(field => field.PunchDate).IsGreaterThan(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));
      })
      .Batch(true)
      .PageSize(20)
      .ServerOperation(false)
      .Events(events => events.Error("gridErrorHandler"))
      .Aggregates(aggrgates => aggrgates.Add(x => x.DurationInSeconds).Sum())
      .Aggregates(aggrgates => aggrgates.Add(x => x.PunchDate).Min())
      .Aggregates(aggrgates => aggrgates.Add(x => x.PunchDate).Max())
      .Model(model =>
      {
          model.Id(x => x.Id);
          model.Field(c => c.Id).Editable(false);
      })
      .Sort(sort =>
      {
          sort.Add(field => field.PunchDate).Descending();
      })

      //.Group(groups=> groups.Add(x=>x.EmployeeName))
      .Group(groups =>
      {
          //groups.Add(x => x.Month);
      })

      .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Punch"))
  //.Create(update => update.Action("Add", "Ticket"))
  //.Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Punch"))
  .Destroy(update => update.Action("Delete", "Punch"))
  )
)
```

This is .CS file

```
public class Punch
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime PunchDate { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan PunchIn { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string Month {
            get
            {
                var In = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(PunchDate.Date + PunchIn,
                    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(User.RegisteredTimeZone));
                return In.ToString("MMMM");
            }
        }
        public TimeSpan? PunchOut { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public string UserGuid { get; set; }


        public bool Approved { get; set; }
        public bool ApprovalRequired { get; set; }
        //[ScaffoldColumn()]
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public string IpAddress { get; set; }
        public string MacAddress { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string EmployeeName => User != null ? $"{User.FirstName} {User.LastName}" : string.Empty;

        public int Hours
        {
            get { return PunchOut.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(PunchOut.Value.Subtract(PunchIn).TotalHours) : 0; }
            set { }
        }

        public double DurationInSeconds { get; set; }


        [NotMapped]
        public TimeSpan Duration
        {
            get
            {
                var Out = PunchOut.HasValue
                    ? TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(PunchDate.Date + PunchOut.Value,
                        TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(User == null ? "India Standard Time" : User.RegisteredTimeZone))
                    : DateTime.MinValue;
                var In = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(PunchDate.Date + PunchIn,
                    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(User == null ? "India Standard Time": User.RegisteredTimeZone));

                if (PunchOut.HasValue)
                {
                    var duration = new TimeSpan(Out.TimeOfDay.Hours, Out.TimeOfDay.Minutes, Out.TimeOfDay.Seconds) -
                                new TimeSpan(In.TimeOfDay.Hours, In.TimeOfDay.Minutes, In.TimeOfDay.Seconds);
                    return duration;
                }
                return DateTime.MinValue.TimeOfDay;
            }
            set { }
        }

        public int ApprovedHours
        {
            get
            {
                if (PunchOut != null)
                    return ApprovalRequired
                        ? (Approved ? PunchOut.Value.Subtract(PunchIn).Seconds : 0)
                        : PunchOut.Value.Subtract(PunchIn).Seconds;
                return 0;
            }
            set { }
        }
```

this is .JS file

```
function onPunchReportExcelExport(e) {
    var sheet = e.workbook.sheets[0];
    var rows = sheet.rows;
    var rowIdx, colIdx, cells, cell;

    for (rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < rows.length; rowIdx++) {
        if (rows[rowIdx].type === "data") {
            cells = rows[rowIdx].cells;
            var color = "#ffffff";
            if (cells[0].value === true) {
                color = "#ff0000";
            }
            for (colIdx = sheet.freezePane.colSplit; colIdx < cells.length; colIdx++) {
                debugger;
                cell = cells[colIdx];

                cell.background = color;
                //cell.value = kendo.toString(cell.value, "c");
                if (colIdx === 6) {
                    cell.value = cell.value.Hours + ":" + cell.value.Minutes;
                }
                else if (cell.value !== undefined && cell.value !== null && cell.value.Hours !== undefined) {
                    cell.value = utcTimeToLocalTime(cell.value.Hours + ":" + cell.value.Minutes);
                }
                else if (cell.value !== undefined && cell.value !== null && cell.value === true) {
                    cell.value = "Yes";
                }
                else if (cell.value !== undefined && cell.value !== null && cell.value === false) {
                    cell.value = "No";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
$(function () {
    var exportFlag = false;
    $("#TimeTrackingLogsGrid").data("kendoGrid").bind("excelExport",
        function (e) {
            if (!exportFlag) {
                var sheet = e.workbook.sheets[0];
                var columns = e.sender.columns;
                //jQuery.each(columns,
                //    function (index) {
                //        if (this.template) {
                //            var template = kendo.template(this.template);

                //            for (var i = 1; i < sheet.rows.length; i++) {
                //                var row = sheet.rows[i];

                //                var dataItem = {
                //                    UnitPrice: row.cells[index].value
                //                };

                //                row.cells[index].value = template(dataItem);
                //            }
                //        }
                //    });

                //var columns = e.sender.columns;
                //jQuery.each(columns,
                //    function (index) {
                //        if (this.attributes !== undefined && this.attributes.class !== undefined) {
                //            if (this.attributes.class === "excel-export-field-hide") {
                //                this.hidden = true;
                //            }
                //            if (this.attributes.class === "excel-export-field-show") {
                //                this.hidden = false;
                //            }
                //        }
                //    });
                //e.sender.showColumn(e.sender.columns.length + 1);
                e.preventDefault();
                exportFlag = true;
                setTimeout(function () {
                        e.sender.saveAsExcel();
                    },
                    1000);
            } else {
                // e.sender.hideColumn(0);
                //e.sender.hideColumn(e.sender.columns.length + 1);
                exportFlag = false;
            }
        });
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrTyU.jpg)

Comment: have you tried making that column into text for the export ?

Comment: hi Nigel Fds.
i din't tried i am following this from this link. http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/excel-export

Comment: ok then can you try making that date column string and then check the output ?